# How can I avoid asking twitter to grant access for my app everytime the user signs in to my WPF program using twitterizer?

Tags: .net, wpf, twitterizer

I'm using twitterizer to signin to my wpf program. Every time when the program is executed, twitter generated pin is stored in a variable and then app runs. Is it possible to authenticate only once and then remember that approval? If possible, then how?

Comment: You need to store the access token and access token secret on disk, then check for those tokens and use them on next startup.

Answer (score 0):

As @BoltClock said, you need to store the token provided by twitter and use it.

Check this link that may help you:

[implementing-sign-twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter)

[authenticate](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authenticate)

Comment: thanks @BoltClock. Another question is also like mine. [Storing Twitter access token using Twitterizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470549/storing-twitter-access-token-using-twitterizer)